# Android studio comment shortcuts

Tags: android-studio

When I hit the shortcut command in Android Studio that comments out a line of code the two slashes go to the begging of the line, leaving empty space in front of the line. Is it possible to align the the two slashes just before the beginning of the code?

```
      //I want to achieve this
//    this happens by default
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **Settings** > **Editor** > **Code Style** > **Java**. Then select the **Code Generation** tab and uncheck the **Line comment at first column** checkbox.

Comment: Wow what an ocean of setting menus. Thank you very much this is exactly what I searched for!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

File-> settings->Editor->java-> Code generation-> 
under **comment code** section uncheck the **Line comment at first column**